# Set the selected index of a dynamic dropdown(DOM) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

**1)Model**

### My index values are stored in int array;

```
Public int[] mobileid { get; set;}
```

**2)View**

```
@for(int i=0;i<3;i++)//Now create 3 dropdown with same name
{
<div>
@html.DropDownlistFor(model=>model.mobileid ,new Selectlist((ViewBag.mobileinfo),"value","Text"),new {@id="ddl"})
</div>
}
```

**3)Script**

### Mobileid have 3 integer value. This values are 2, 3 4 How to set selected value above the 3 dropdown

```
$("#ddl").val('2');
$("#ddl").val('3');
$("#ddl").val('4');
```

**When my dropdownload ,this values show the 1st position**

Comment: You can't have three select boxes with the same `id`. It's invalid. `id` values must be **unique**.

Comment: i can get selected value in control side with the same id,When click edit button  i can't set selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have three select boxes with the same `id`. It's invalid. `id` values must be **unique**.

Instead, either give them different `id`s, e.g.:

```
@for(int i=0;i<3;i++)//Now create 3 dropdown with same name
{
<div>
@html.DropDownlistFor(model=>model.mobileid ,new Selectlist((ViewBag.mobileinfo),"value","Text"),new {@id="ddl" + i})
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
</div>
}
```

...and then use `$("#ddl0")`, `$("#ddl1")`, etc.

Or give them a common *name* or *class*, and then use jQuery's `.eq(n)` to choose each of them. For names: `$("[name=ddl]").eq(0)`, `$("[name=ddl]").eq(1)` etc.; for a class: `$(".ddl").eq(0)`, `$(".ddl").eq(1)`

Comment: <script>var id=@html.raw(json.Encode(model.mobileid)); </script> not working.How to set int array value in var datatype

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto: Dunno, that's a different question, and I'm not familiar with the technology you're using.